# Beginner: Why does terminal command rails g controller pages '' '' perform but no folders are created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYHQr.jpg)
[text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmtrF.jpg)

I'm following a beginners tutorial at Code4Startup.com and following video 2, but am confused as to why terminal runs the command but doesnt generate the folders like the video shows.  Also, is 'identical' stated because I've run the g command a few times?  Any help is much appreciated.

I tried linking the Code4Startup page I'm working from but am not reputable enough for 3 links.

Comment: Yes you are getting "identical" because you are running the same generator multiple times.  Chances are the folders/files are getting generated and you just need to refresh your file view.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.  Sorry my response is late I didnt' get a chance to look at it this weekend.  Looking now through the folder I created and saved on desktop and it doesn't show the controllers I generated in terminal either.  So, refreshing (just closing the editor and re-opening the file in it) didn't solve it.  Other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Steve already answered this but when you press Rails g Blah 
Rails looks in the folder which it currently is in... For the files and folders it is supposed to create such as the test folder, the CSS file, the views, the model whatever it is that you are generating at the time. If those are generated it tells you identical. Otherwise, it will generate them and give you a green message. I would be that you are not in the correct Directory. Try to `cd name` of the project...
for instance Inside your CLI (command Line Interface) Like terminal/bash/Command Prompt... accessible by typing windowkey+space in Linux or command+space in mac then Terminal....
Type the following commands:

```
cd
mkdir Projects
cd Projects
rails new Pizzeria
cd Pizzeria
rails g model Pizza name:string vegetarian:bool description:text 
rails g controller Pizzas index show edit
rake db:migrate
"You get an error message: undefined method `bool'" --Oopsie
rails destroy model Pizza name vegetarian description
rails g model Pizza name:string vegetarian:boolean description:text
rails s
```

This will create a projects folder, enter the projects folder, create a new rails project, enter rails project, generate user model, migrate user model into active record. Then start the rails server.

After that you can visit your rails project at: `http://localhost:3000/` in the browser.

Your next steps are to set up `config/routes` with all the routes you need for your pizzeria by uncommenting the `resources:` section and filling in Pizza.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Sorry I'm late getting to work on it, but doing so now.  The last part 'rake db:migrate' is the only command not included in the video and the instructor seems to jump from 'rails g model ##' to his editor and the files appear.  Not so in my case, although they are generated it terminal as my screenshots show.  I'l try the rake bit now and get back to you.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, I've got it.  I deleted my original files and recreated with your direction and it appears.  Thanks m8 I appreciate the help.

Comment: If you found it helpful, mark it as correct I also add a few more instructions in case you might find them helpful.

Comment: Reed it seems that Zargold's answer helped you out. I politely encourage you to **accept** his answer.